# Visual Basic PowerPacks from Visual studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2012 express. Fail to create component

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I had an application in Visual studio 2008 (Visual Basic) and installed visual studio express 2012, when I tried to add a DataRepeater to a new form in my existing project, it says that already exists, same thing when I try to add PrintForm. 
I can not add a new of this objects in any new or pre-existen form.

This is the content of the message that I received:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop
---------------------------
Failed to create component 'DataRepeater'.  The error message follows:

 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004D745): A reference to the component 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs' already exists in the project.

   at VSLangProj.References.Add(String bstrPath)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.PerformReferenceUpdate(List`1 newReferences)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.System.ComponentModel.Design.ITypeResolutionService.ReferenceAssembly(AssemblyName name)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.ReferenceAssembly(AssemblyName name)

   at System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.GetType(IDesignerHost host, AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean reference)

   at System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host)

   at System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host, IDictionary defaultValues)

   at System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponents(IDesignerHost host, IDictionary defaultValues)

   ...'
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

It says something about reference update, I am not experienced developer in vb.net, so not sure where should I go to fix it and how.